# Find json fields (geolocation from ip)

Tags: php, json, geolocation

I'm trying find the fields *latitude* and *longitude* respectivally from a json document where contains some informations of geolocation of a visitor based in your ip address with following code but seems not work:

```
$User_Latitude = $jsondata["latitude"];
$User_Longitude = $jsondata["longitude"];
```

where is my error?

full code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

    $freegeoipjson = unserialize(curl_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/". $ip .""));
    $jsondata = json_decode($freegeoipjson);
    $User_Latitude = $jsondata["latitude"];
    $User_Longitude = $jsondata["longitude"];

    $url = sprintf("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%s,%s", $User_Latitude, $User_Longitude);
    $content = curl_get_contents($url); // get json content
    $metadata = json_decode($content, true); //json decoder
    if(count($metadata['results']) > 0)
    {
        $result = $metadata['results'][0];
        $User_location=$result['formatted_address']; // Address into normalize format.
    }
    echo $User_location;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you are getting the right data back from the curl function, there's two changes that you need to make:

1. Looks like you don't need the unserialize call (returned data doesn't look serialized to me)
2. Pass a second "true" parameter to the json_decode function to make sure you actually get an array back in the $jsondata variable.

Here are the two modified lines:

```
$freegeoipjson = curl_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/". $ip);
$jsondata = json_decode($freegeoipjson, true);
```

Comment: in my case if i set **true** to `json_decode()` will fail. The correct is: `$freegeoipjson = curl_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/". $ip ."");
$jsondata = json_decode($freegeoipjson);`. Please edit your answer and i will erase this comment.

Comment: I don't quite follow, sorry. Are you saying everything works fine how you had it originally? I tested the json_decode without the second parameter and it doesn't work as expected, as you will get back an Object instead of array.

Comment: seems that these difference are relative to some setting on your host. But even so, i will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks. So what was the cause of the error in your initial code then?

Comment: `unserialize` unnecessary and fields must be accessed like this: `$jsondata->latitude; $jsondata->longitude;`